# Fresh Rails install on Mac OS X gives me "Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I just set up a fresh Mac OS X 10.5 environment for Rails.  I installed Ruby 1.8.7, renamed the packaged version of Ruby in /usr/bin, and updated the packaged version of RubyGems from 1.0.1 to 1.3.4.  Here's the flow:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.4
$ gem -v
1.3.4
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ whereis gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
$ whereis rails
/usr/bin/rails
$ /usr/bin/gem -v
1.3.4
$ /usr/bin/rails -v
Rails 2.3.4
$ rails testapp
...
...
testapp $ script/console
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2.  Please install RubyGems and try again:  http://rubygems.rubyforge.org
```

The thing is I've updated RubyGems and didn't install another version of it.  `gem list rails` displays two versions of Rails (2.3.4 and 1.2.6), though.

How can I fix this so I can use Rails?

Comment: Just curious, are using 'sudo gem ...' when you do all your gem stuff.?I've noticed this does affect things on certain systems. I'm on a mac myself and try to make sure any gem stuff is always done through sudo.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to not change the system versions, instead install in /usr/local or use MacPorts.

The guys over at [HiveLogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard) cover Rails, as well as MySQL and other development tools.

Using these techniques i've successfully installed rails into /usr/local  Then it's a simple matter of adjusting the path settings in your terminal shell via (export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

That should get you the latest version of rubygems, which is something like 1.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will tell you the version of RubyGems you have if it's loading an incompatible version.  The error message you're getting means it can't load RubyGems at all, so I'm thinking it's a path issue.

What do you get from `$:` in irb?  Is there a `rubygems.rb` in any of those locations?

Comment: I didn't see it; how can I fix this?  I don't get why it's not there when I just upgraded the existing RubyGems install on Mac OSX - wouldn't it have been set already?

Comment: I think I see the problem, but I'm not sure.  running gem environment shows my Ruby version as 1.8.6 but I installed 1.8.7.  I think because I only installed the new version of Ruby but kept and updated the original version of gems, there's some weirdness going on there.

Comment: FYI I'm keeping the default rubygems install because I ran into some issues trying to install things that expect the default gem location; I'm a newb to command line stuff :(

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and use Macports instead of trying updatre and repalce the core system libraries. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I second that emotion and, if I could, would up-vote the answer from prodigitalson -- MacPorts is your friend...  Recommend you run specifically:

> $ sudo port install rubygem
>
> $ gem install rails

Key is making your `which ruby` and your rubygems `which gem` in synch. and in harmony...both should be in /opt/local/bin/

So Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 working on my MacOS 10.5.8 - and the `gem environment` no longer lies after the MacPorts install and reports the correct version, 1.8.7.

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-9
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/saleram/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is rather old, and comments stale, current searchers may find that these instructions:

[Installing Rails on Mac OS X 10.6 (SL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844795/installing-rails-on-mac-os-x-10-6-sl)

work fine for installing Ruby / Rails 3 on new OS X 10.6 installs, GIVEN that you install a recent version of RubyGems:

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126

... particularly, do this in place of typing

```
sudo update_rubygems
```

in the first of my links

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here's what I did that solved it:

First, update gem

```
gem update --system
```

Navigate to the primary path in `gem env`, in my case **/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8**

```
cd /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
```

Then, navigate to the gem itself:

```
cd gems/rubygems-update-1.3.5
```

Run setup.rb

```
sudo setup.rb
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [BitNami Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) as an alternative? It is a free installer that provides a out-of-the-box Rails environment with MySQL (and a bunch of preconfigured, commonly used third-party libraries and apps). Please note I am one of the contributors to RubyStack, so I am biased. It is free and distributed under the Apache 2.0 open source license

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation with the company each time you mention your product. Otherwise, it is considered as spam here.

Comment: I have done so in most other questions and is clearly specified in my profile as well. BitNami is not a company, and we do not make any money with the stacks (though it is sponsored by one and we provide support and services to some other open source companies such as Sugar, Alfresco, etc.). In any case, I have now updated my response. Also, I believe there was no need to downvote the answer as it is directly related to the topic.

Comment: I did not downvote. The spam flag works like that. It will go away after a while now that you updated your answer. Note however that you really should specify your affiliation in each of your answers, it is not enough to have it on your profile, so you should check that all your answers recommending your products include a disclaimer