# Installing Rails on Mac OS X 10.6 (SL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, installation

I've just gone to installed RoR on my snow leopard mac.. and found the rails gem was already installed..

is this normal? Does it need updating?

Does this get installed along with textmate?

Answer (score 3):

It is installed with the Snow Leopard developer tools. Version 1.8.7 of Ruby is installed.

You should be fine for most your development needs. If you wish to upgrade just update the gems:

```
$ sudo gem install rubygems-update

$ sudo update_rubygems

$ sudo gem update

$ sudo gem update --system

$ sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: rails 3 is in beta right now, and it is not installed with SL

Answer (score 1):

I found an **incredibly** well written install guide at The Pragmatic Studio called [Installing Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3 on Mac OS X](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac).  It took about an hour to follow, including installing several prerequisites.

I'm hesitant to mess too much with OSX's native installation of ruby/rails, lest things get broken by an Apple system update, so I was very excited to learn about [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](http://beginrescueend.com/) which is a cool tool for switching between different ruby/rails installations.  The Pragmatic Studio tutorial walks you through installing rvm.

There are a few glitches with the guide, which I'll list here:

- Git: I just installed git itself.  You do not need to set up a github account.
- Git: You *may* need to manually add /usr/local/git/bin to your PATH.  (They don't explicitly tell you to)
- RVM: The protocol for the rvm-install-head URL should be https, not http
- RVM: The installer complained a lot, but it worked anyway.
- RVM: The newly installed ruby 1.9.2 didn't activate until I ran 'rvm 1.9.2' in step 8

All told, this seems like a GREAT approach, and I'm really impressed with their install guide!

Comment: BTW, Rails 3 is no longer beta.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the rails gem is already installed along with Snow Leopard, because you installed developer tools, it's very normal.

But it's a little bit old, you need to update it.

TextMate did not bundle any RoR stuff with this. TextMate just included a lot of bundles which mainly consists of Python and Ruby scripts, if you do not have ruby, textmate will not work.

However, TextMate is originally made on Tiger 10.4, which bundled Ruby 1.8.2, and Snow Leopard bundled Ruby 1.8.7, so TextMate's bundles is not fully compatible with Snow Leopard
Refer to this and get some fix for these issues:

http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/SnowLeopard

And also make sure you always keep your RoR bundle to the latest SVN is also a good habit

Answer (score 0):

TextMate is just a text editor. It only understands Rails syntax and file structure making it easy to write Rails apps. That said, you still need to install Rails separately to create Rails apps.

Answer (score 0):

well for me it worked [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/)... I have mountain lion but it worked just fine...